# Replace a newline with underscore '_' in bash variable

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I know I can replace a newline with a space using sed (in a file) using

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file.txt
```

But how can I **replace a newline with a underscore '_' in a bash variable**?

I tried to replace it with a space to test it out but that didn't work see what I used below.

```
#gets rid of newline and replace with space to get station name on one line
station=$(
<<<"${station_tmp}"\
echo $station_tmp | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' 
)
```

variable station_tmp looks like:

```
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
```

I'm trying to replace the newlines with underscores '_' and have it look like:

```
1st line_2nd line_3rd line
```

Ps I'm using Ubuntu 18:04 64bit linux

Comment: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' <<< "$station_tmp"`?

Comment: With pure Bash you can do ```var=${var/^M/_}``` where ```^M``` is typed as `Ctrl-v` `Ctrl-m`.

Comment: @accdias control-M isn't a newline in UNIX though - it's `\r` (carriage return) instead of `\n` (linefeed aka newline in UNIX).

Comment: @EdMorton, always right. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "$var" | paste -sd_
```

Where variable value is:

```
echo "$var"
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in bash itself:

```
var='1st line
2nd line
3rd line'

echo "${var//$'\n'/_}"
```

```
1st line_2nd line_3rd line
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
<<<"$var" sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;y/\n/_/'
```

or:

```
<<<"$var" sed -z 'y/\n/_/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one which works:

```
awk -v ORS="_" '1' <<<"$var"
```